# Finding the nth derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How does one prove the following result regarding the nth derivative.

For 
$y= \left ( x^{2} +1\right )^{n}$
prove that 
$y_{2n} = 2n!$, where
$y_{2n} $ represents the $2n^{th}$ derivative.

The main task at hand being generalizing the expression for first, second, and third derivative, which I am unable to do.

Comment: Note that $(x^2+1)^n=x^{2n}+$lower terms.

Comment: @Hagen Well thank you. That indeed helps. Wondering now why I did not use Binomial Expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Proving the formula for $y^{(2n)}$ doesn't really involve doing anything smart about the "lower" derivatives.

You just note that

$$
y = (x^2+1)^n = x^{2n} + P(x),
$$
where $P(x)$ has degree at most $2n-1$. It means that $2n$'th derivative of $P(x)$ is $0$, so $y^{(2n)} = (x^{2n})^{(2n)} = (2n)!$.

Comment: Hagen above said the same thing. I was foolish.